# Ceiling fan outlet wire codes, help with Lutron mastero fan and light switch

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have two ceiling fan outlets in different rooms with different color wired.

1 room has
Yellow, brown and two white wires.
Yellow and brown are shorted
Two whites are shorted.

[image]

2 room has
brown, yellow and Black separate.

[image]
I want to have separate wall control for fan and light.

My fan has white black and blue wires (includes light kit)
I would like to use Lutron light and fan control switch.

Please help me understand which wire goes where.

Thanks

Comment: Do you know which wallboxes control these ceiling outlets?

Comment: Do the room wall-boxes actually have separate switches for light and fan?  Are you SURE the colors are actually yellow (not yellowed white) and actually black (not really a mid-gray)?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, you can see them in the picture, colors are correct.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I am not sure, I need to check with builder.

Comment: @akan I ask because I do a lot with color, and phone cameras can really mess up color in the course of trying to white-balance...